# Convert custom type to QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have my custom type:

```
enum class MyType : int {
     TYPENAME1 = 0,
     TYPENAME2 = 1,
     TYPENAME3 = 2
};
```

I need to convert `MyType` to `QVariant`. I tried `qDebug() << QVariant::fromValue(value)` but I received `" "` instead of property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QVariant to store a custom type, you need the type to be registered with the qt meta object system.

1. `Q_ENUM` or `Q_ENUM_NS` in the header of the type
2. `qRegisterMetaType<MyType>()` called sometime before you try to use the type with QVariant (usually setup somewhere that is called when your app starts)